Create local administrator account with PowerShell
Is there a way to create an admin user for all clients without disabling the firewall on the client or enabling PSRemoting on the client using PowerShell in the domain controller?
I used the following script:
# Define variables
$computers = Get-Content 
C:\Computers.txt
$username = "AdminLocal"
$password = "password"
$fullname = "Admin"
$local_security_group = 
"Administrators"
$description = "Description"
$offlineComputers = @() # Array to 
store offline computers

Foreach ($computer in $computers) {
$users = $null
$comp = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer"


# Test if the computer is online
$ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet

if ($ping) {
    # Check if username exists
Try {
    $users = $comp.psbase.children | select -expand name
    if ($users -contains $username) {
        Write-Host "$computer -> $username already exists on $computer" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    } else {
        # Create the account
        $user = $comp.Create("User", "$username")
        $user.SetPassword("$password")
        $user.Put("Description", "$description")
        $user.Put("Fullname", "$fullname")
        $user.SetInfo()

        # Set password to never expire
        # And set user cannot change password
        $ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = 0x10000
        $ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE = 0x40
        $user.userflags = $ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD + $ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE
        $user.SetInfo()

        # Add the account to the local admins group
        $group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$local_security_group,group"
        $userPath = "WinNT://$computer/$username,user"
        $group.Add($userPath)

        # Validate whether user account has been created or not
        $users = $comp.psbase.children | select -expand name
        if ($users -contains $username) {
            Write-Host "$computer -> $username has been created on $computer and added to the Administrators group" -ForegroundColor Green
        } else {
            Write-Host "$computer -> $username has not been created on $computer" -ForegroundColor Magenta
        }
    }
} Catch {
    Write-Host "$computer -> Error creating $username on $($computer.path): $($Error[0].Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}

}else{
    Write-Host "$computer -> $computer is offline. Skipping..." -ForegroundColor Gray
        $offlineComputers += $computer # Add offline computer to the list
}

}
It works correctly, if the firewall is disabled.
If the firewall is active, in addition to no ping, the following error occurs:
"The following exception occurred while retrieving member "name":
"Not implemented"
